# What is the reason for the error message "Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib"?

Tags: mysql, perl, dynamic-loading

I have no experience working with Perl, and I'm trying to run [the `geo_to_mysql.pl` program](http://genotext.stanford.edu/geo_to_mysql.pl) for a project I'm working on. I made no modifications to the program other than the database, username, password and file directory path in the first few lines.

When running the program, I keep getting this error:

> install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't load '/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle' for module DBD::mysql: dlopen(/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle, 1): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
>
> Referenced from: /Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle
>
> Reason: image not found at /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 207.
>
> at (eval 7) line 3
>
> Compilation failed in require at (eval 7) line 3.
>
> Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where expected

I've made sure that I installed the DBD required for MySQL from CPAN, so I don't think that's the issue. Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Perl's DBI (database interface) module requires a DBD (database driver) for each database type you're connecting to. Looks like you're missing the DBD for MySQL. It should be easily installable from CPAN, or available as a pre-built package for your system somewhere.

Comment: I installed the DBD::mysql from CPAN, but I'm still getting the exact same error message...any thoughts? Thanks again :)

Comment: Did you compile DBD::mysql? Run the tests?

Comment: How did you install mysql? How do you call the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DBD::mysql module needs access to the MySQL client libraries in order to work. I'm surprised that DBD::mysql even installed without them being on your system. How did you install the DBD::mysql module?

Comment: I followed these instructions: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.019/INSTALL.html

Comment: Like i said, i pretty much have no idea what I'm doing here... I've already installed MySQL and these other relevant software though, following instructions listed on the respective websites. Any ideas are much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

It sure sounds like you might want to read this blog post:

http://probably.co.uk/problems-installing-dbdmysql-on-os-x-snow-leopard.html

The issue seems to be that the mysqlclient dynamic library doesn't have path information in it.  You need to manaully fix this (as the post above notes).

One of the cheaper solutions is to symlink or copy the libmysqlclient library to /usr/lib.

Hope this helps anyone looking for this question in the future.

Comment: Also, make sure your using the right mysql arch with your perl.  I'm using 32bit perl.  mysql x86_64 won't work with that, I think.

Comment: I encountered exactly the same problem. Copying libmysqlclient to /usr/lib and reinstalling DBD::mysql did the trick.

Comment: Worked for me when attempting to install DBD::mysql on OSX Yosemite. I created a symlink to the dylib in /usr/lib and all was well: `sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib`